# Android refreshing listview after clicking button

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to refresh a ListView getting text from an `ArrayList<String>` after clicking a button.

Before clicking, my `ListView` is filled with the first string found in the `ArrayList` (I did that using `subList(0,1)`).

All I want is to find the next string in the `arrayList` and put it on the `ListView`. I tried the following but it returns error putting the adapter into the `onClick` method.

```
    package com.android.quizzle;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.*;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {



ListView ls1;

String result = null;

String result2 = null;

InputStream is = null;

StringBuilder sb=null;

StringBuilder sb2=null;

JSONArray jArray;

String domande;

String risposta;

RadioGroup radioGroup;

private RadioButton radio1;

private RadioButton radio2;

private RadioButton radio3;

private RadioButton radio4;

private Button nextQuest;

TextView t1;

ArrayList<String> strings2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> risposte = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> risp = new ArrayList<String>();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)

{
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String user = b.getString("il dato inserito è: " );
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Benvenuto: " + user ,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //array list per memorizzare l'output json


         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.managerdb);
         ls1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
         radio1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
         radio2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
         radio3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
         radio4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        //prossima domanda
         nextQuest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNextQuest);
         t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        nextQuest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String risp = null;
                ListView ls1;
                if(v == nextQuest)
                {

                if(radio1.isChecked() == true)
                {
                        risp=risposte.get(0);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), risp ,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //HERE I PUT MY ADAPTER BUT IT GIVES ME ERROR

    ls1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            strings2.subList(0, 1)));
    ls1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                }
                if(radio2.isChecked() == true)
                {
                        risp=risposte.get(1);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), risp ,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                if(radio3.isChecked() == true)
                {
                    risp=risposte.get(3);
                }
                if(radio4.isChecked() == true)
                {
                    risp=risposte.get(4);
                }
                }


            }




         });



    // query post.

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));


    // http post

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://labinform.altervista.org/Android/quiz.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine());
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);

        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();



        if(result.contains("0") || result.contains("1"))
       { 
           Toast.makeText(MainMenuActivity.this, "Seleziona una categoria di apprendimento" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
       }
        else{
           Toast.makeText(MainMenuActivity.this, "Non hai ancora compilato un quiz" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    retrieveArray();
        }}
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    }


    private void retrieveArray() {

        //arrayList per memorizzare il profilo

        //nuova connessione alla pagina contenente i quiz.
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://labinform.altervista.org/Android/tag.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs2));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            sb2.append(reader.readLine());
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb2.append(line);               
            }
            is.close();
            result2 = sb2.toString();


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        //parsing data to Json


    try{

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result2);

        jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("domande");
        JSONArray jArray2 = jObject.getJSONArray("risposte");


        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {                        
            domande=jArray.getString(i);
            strings2.add(domande);     
        }
        for(int k=0;k<jArray2.length();k++){
        risposta = jArray2.getString(k);
        risposte.add(risposta);
        }


    }catch(JSONException e1){

    }catch(Exception e1){
        Log.e("log_tag", "error " + e1.toString());

    } 



    ls1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            strings2.subList(0, 1)));
    ls1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    radio1.setText(risposte.get(0));
    radio2.setText(risposte.get(1));
    radio3.setText(risposte.get(2));
    radio4.setText(risposte.get(3));

}
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Its better to put the part of the code where the problem arise with the logcat saying the error

Comment: The problem is not about logcat. You can see in the code posted above the comment: //HERE I PUT MY ADAPTER BUT IT GIVES ME ERROR

    ls1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            strings2.subList(0, 1)));
    ls1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

it's a problem about Eclipse especially in method onClick(). It seems like i can't declare the adapter inside that. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        strings2.subList(0, 1)));
```

Instead of `this`, which is the OnClickListener(), pass the Application Context.

This can be accomplished by storing the application context before you define the listener:

```
Context context = this;
```

And passing the `context` variable instead of `this`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I really appreciate that. I have another question: done this, i can refresh my radio button? And if it is possible how can i do that? Thanks a loottt!

Comment: Please format a new question if you have one. Also, try to make your question easy to read and straightforward. Do as much research as you can before you are sure you cannot figure out your problem.